# How can we detect gravity phase-shift in quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, gravity, experimental-physics

I have been searching for a satisfying answer on how we can detect the predicted phase shift due to the gravitational potential in quantum mechanics. Specifically, Sakurai, describes in his book the "Gravity - induced quantum interference" and calculates the phase shift. He then mentions that this phase shift has been experimentally detected.

However, since an additional phase doesn't actually affect the expectation values of observables how can we detect it experimentally?

Answer (score 5):

We can detect this using interferometry.

It is true that a phase change on a state, e.g., $\psi\rightarrow e^{i\phi}\psi$ ($\phi$ is a constant) will not change the value of quantities involving inner products e.g., $\langle\psi|O|\psi\rangle$ since
the phase factors cancel. But here Sakurai is referring to particles that interact with a *gravitational field* such that an **interference pattern** can be detected.

In [this](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1975PhRvL..34.1472C/abstract) paper, a neutron interferometer is used to detect the phase shift of *neutrons* interacting with Earth's gravitational field. Some researchers have hypothesized that this, and similar methods of interferometry can be used to (indirectly) detect gravitational waves.

Edit: [MarkH](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/45164/mark-h) has commented of [simplified explanation](https://skullsinthestars.com/2015/05/20/1975-the-year-that-quantum-mechanics-met-gravity/) of the paper above which is also helpful to anyone who hasn't got access to *Physical Review Letters*. Thanks Mark.

Comment: Here's a blog post written by a physicist that explains the experiment for those that can't access the journal article: https://skullsinthestars.com/2015/05/20/1975-the-year-that-quantum-mechanics-met-gravity/

Comment: @MarkH Thanks Mark. I forgot that not everyone can access PRL. If it's okay with you, I'll use your link in my answer as well. Cheers.

Comment: No problem. Go ahead.